# Linker doesn't see function inside .lib

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, linker

I'm writing a small Win32 application in Visual Studio C/C++ that talks to a HID device using the WDK.

I've added the following include directories in Options > Projects and Solutions > VC++ Directories:

```
D:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\inc\ddk
D:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\inc\api
```

And the following library directory:

```
D:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\lib\win7\i386
```

I also set the following lib file to Project Properties > Configuration Properties > Linker > Additional Dependencies:

```
hid.lib
```

But when I try to compile, I get:

```
error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000040) "unsigned char __stdcall HidD_SetOutputReport(void *,void *,unsigned long)" ...
```

Although, this should be in hid.lib

Am I missing something ?

**-- Update --**
At the suggestion of SooWeiTan I enabled Properties->Linker->Show Progress and now I see here the following:

```
1>    Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\lib\MSCOREE.lib:
1>      Found __CorExeMain@0
1>        Loaded MSCOREE.lib(mscoree.dll)
1>      Found __IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR_mscoree
1>        Referenced in MSCOREE.lib(mscoree.dll)
1>        Loaded MSCOREE.lib(mscoree.dll)
1>      Found mscoree_NULL_THUNK_DATA
1>        Referenced in MSCOREE.lib(mscoree.dll)
1>        Loaded MSCOREE.lib(mscoree.dll)
1>    Searching D:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\lib\win7\i386\hid.lib:
1>    Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\lib\kernel32.lib:
...
...
...
```

From this, I interpret that it doesn't find anything interesting in the hid.lib, whereas it should find my trouble function... Any idea why this could happen ?

Comment: Not enough information. Example: you could be trying to link the wrong bitness. Besides: use VisualDDK and get the preconfigured project "for free".

Comment: I would enable Properties->Linker->Show Progress and observe the output.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED Will it work to create a Windows application that just talk to a driver ? I thought that was for when you want to write a driver ...

Comment: @SooWeiTan I will try that as soon as I get back home

Comment: @Nicolae: right, sorry. Then DDKWizard may be the way to go. It allows to create "normal" Win32 projects based on msvcrt.dll (VS 6 C runtime).

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED Ok, VisualDDK is a blast. Where it was when I wrote the driver? :)) But I believe that what you are suggesting is to start with a driver environment and make the proper adjustments to make it a Win32 app... My fear is that I will end up in the same scenario, only now I walked the path the other way around ...

Comment: @SooWeiTan Please see the update to the question. Thank you

Comment: Still more info needed. `dumpbin /exports hid.lib|findstr HidD_SetOutputReport` should list it. But to be honest I get the feeling that the `.lib` may simply have been created with a newer linker than your Visual Studio has. You haven't given any info about you VS (version, patch-level).

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2008 v9.0.21022.8 RTM & .NET Version 3.5 SP1 . The output of the dumpbin is empty :|, even if I remove the findstr part. Does this mean that your linker assumption was correct ? Cause the msdn clearly states that the function is in hid.lib: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff539690(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: PS: I see that in other libs from WDK it finds functions (in `kernel32.lib` for example)

Comment: I'm out of ideas - your linker is obviously finding `hib.lib`, but `dumpbin /exports hid.lib|findstr HidD_SetOutputReport` reports nothing? I have no answers to this for now...

BTW are you compiling with /clr by design? I wonder if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED I've tried what is suggested in he answer below, and now dumpbin find the function inside the .lib (`_HidD_SetOutputReport@12`). Any ideas why that fix it and how it may help me fix my issue ?

Comment: @SooWeiTan Yes, I use /clr for this project, because the rest of the app is written in C++. Please see the answer bellow and my reply to it for latest news about the dumpbin issue. Maybe some toughs on the new development ? :(

Comment: Wait wait wait. Your above output (the one you edited in) shows a path pointing to the `wxp` folder, while your question states that you used the `win7` folder. Are any global settings overshadowing the project-local ones?

Comment: Sorry, it was just me playing back a forth between Win7 and winxp trying to solve the problem. I corrected the edit, sorry for the confusion ... Both using win7 and winxp will have the same outcome :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm ashamed to say that I found the problem :(. I'm C\C++ noob, but still ...

When I was importing the C modules inside the c++ files, there was no `extern "C"` arround the include :|

Answer (score 0):

I see you probably have MS SDK.

- Start cmd.exe,
- go to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\" --will be probably 6.0 on yours
- run "SetEnv.cmd /x86"
- go to the directory with the lib
- run "dumpbin /exports hid.lib | findstr HidD_SetOutputReport"

then if you get nothing, it's obvious the lib just does not contain that function (might as well try just some parts of the function's name to make sure). If you get something, the path to the lib is wrong. That is really all that could cause the problem. If there is a problem with running setenv, other way should be going to directory with MSVC you are using, then go to VC\bin and run vcvars32.bat, that should do the same thing.

Comment: After following your instruction, now dumbbin.exe will output `_HidD_SetOutputReport@12`. If you look in the update for the question, you'll see in the output of the linker that it sees the hid.lib inside WDK, it just that it doesn't find the function inside ...